# How to define a field using a nested for loop in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

```
resources = ["s3", "nsn"]
envs = ["prd", "dev"]
```

I want the output to be:

```
hashed = {
  s3 = { 
    prd = "abcd-1234-5678-s3-prod" 
    dev = "abcd-1234-5678-s3-dev"
  }
  sns = { 
    prd = "abcd-1234-5678-sns-prod" 
    dev = "abcd-1234-5678-sns-dev"
  }
}
```

We can access them with code `hashed.s3.dev` in order to get `abcd-1234-5678-s3-dev`.

What I tried:

```
hashed = concat([
  for resource in resources : [
    for env in envs : 
      env => join("-", compact([var.random, var.random, resource, env]))
  }
])
```

Output I got:

```
hashed = [
  { prd = "abcd-1234-5678-s3-prod" 
   dev = "abcd-1234-5678-s3-dev"
  },
  { prd = "abcd-1234-5678-sns-prod" 
    dev = "abcd-1234-5678-sns-dev"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed your code slightly:

```
locals {
  resources = ["s3", "sns"]
  envs = ["prd", "dev"]
}

output "hashed" {
  value = {
    for resource in local.resources : resource => {
      for env in local.envs :
      env => join("-", compact(["var1", "var2", resource, env]))
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
hashed = {
  "s3" = {
    "dev" = "var1-var2-s3-dev"
    "prd" = "var1-var2-s3-prd"
  }
  "sns" = {
    "dev" = "var1-var2-sns-dev"
    "prd" = "var1-var2-sns-prd"
  }
}
```

Terraform `for` expressions - https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for#result-types.